# ContextMenu Closes Immediately after Removing and Adding the same item

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu, itemscontrol

I am having a very stange problem and I really have to fix it.

In this TestProject, there is a simple view:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}" Fill="{Binding Color}" Stroke="Black" MouseUp="Rectangle_MouseUp">
                <Rectangle.Resources>
                    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="DataContext" Data="{Binding Path=.}"/>
                </Rectangle.Resources>
                <Rectangle.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ContextMenu IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen}" DataContext="{Binding Path=Data, Source={StaticResource DataContext}}">
                                    <MenuItem Header="Test"/>
                                </ContextMenu>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Rectangle.Style>
            </Rectangle>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
<Button Content="Remove and Add again the green one" Height="50" Click="ButtonAddRemove_Click" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

ItemsControl - Elements with ContextMenu.

I want the ContextMenu to be shown when I set my Property IsOpen to true.

```
private void Rectangle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
    {
        var Rect = (sender as Rectangle).DataContext as MyRectangle;
        Rect.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

This Works.

But after removing and adding the same item:

```
private void ButtonAddRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var Last = Rectangles.LastOrDefault();
    Rectangles.Remove(Last);
    Rectangles.Add(Last);
}
```

The ContextMenu appears and disappears immediately again.

If someone is missing any code or wants to try my project:
[TestProject.zip](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10832438/TestProject.zip.html)

Thank you so much!